# a function that finds every array within a single array

Tags: php, arrays

hey guys please help me out with this.
am trying to write a function that finds every array within and array then modify all arrays found.

I have achieved the first goal, the second not quite.

here is the function so far.

```
  $count = 0;
  function findObj($arr) {
    global $count;

    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
      if(gettype($arr[$key]) == 'array') {
        // append the string "here" to the array found
        $arr[$key][] = 'here';
        $count++;
        // call same function within function with the argument of array found
        findObj($arr[$key]);
      }
    }

    $rtnArr = [$count, $arr];
    return $rtnArr;
  }

  var_dump(findArr($arr));
  // this returns

  array (size=5)
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 44
  2 => int 43
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'hello' (length=5)
      1 => string 'here' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'one' (length=3)
      1 => string 'two' (length=3)
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'three' (length=5)
          1 => string 'four' (length=4)
      3 => string 'here' (length=4)
```

only the arrays in the first level where modified. please help my brain is about to explode().

Comment: array_walk_recursive?

Comment: @Progrock that is amazing thanks, buh the way <code>array_walk_recursive</code> i can't really modify it the way i want, i found a solution to my function though "Passing Arguments by Reference &". anyway thanks i've learned a new function.

Comment: Sorry for the red herring.

Comment: no probs, we never stop learning. and thanks!, your function is way less messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$input =
[
    [
        'foo',
        [
            'bar',
            'baz',
            [
                'bat',
                'man'
            ]
         ]
    ]
];

function add_extra_element_recursive(array &$array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => &$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            add_extra_element_recursive($value);
        }
    }
    $array[] = 'extra';
}

var_export($input);
echo "\n";
add_extra_element_recursive($input);
var_export($input);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'bar',
      1 => 'baz',
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'bat',
        1 => 'man',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 
    array (
      0 => 'bar',
      1 => 'baz',
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => 'bat',
        1 => 'man',
        2 => 'extra',
      ),
      3 => 'extra',
    ),
    2 => 'extra',
  ),
  1 => 'extra',
)
```